# Avoid html encoded characters in soap web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have developped a soap web service with C#.
When the customers use my web service, the collected data are html encoded (ex

> `&amp;`

).
How can I avoid this encoding and let special characters in collected data ?
Is there a parameter or a header to set for my web service ?
I would like to avoid decode the encoded data.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards.

Eric

Comment: encode is letting special characters in data. You should encode and decode. Even more, I would suggest stop doing SOAP services and begin make RESTful API

Comment: You will probably want to utilize [WebUtility.HtmlDecode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=net-8.0#system-net-webutility-htmldecode(system-string))

Comment: HTML encoding if I'm not mistaken is a standard to maximize compatibility, so attempting to do away w it would probably not be worth the hassle if it means further problems. Take the strings in and validate them w a call to HtmlDecode

Comment: Thanks a lot Leandro and Narish for your comments, I will consider to decode the data, if there is no other solution.